# Как сделать DISTINCT только по двум полям?

Tags: mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать DISTINCT по полям brand и article, хотя в select мне надо указать 3 поля?
Начало запроса

```
select
  distinct `brand1` as `brand`,
  `article1` as `article`,
  `title2` as `title`
from .........
```

Нужно показать уникальные значения только по полям brand и article но в выдаче должен быть еще и title

Comment: А что должно выводить, если brand1 будет 5 штук, например, а article1 - 10?

Comment: А если title будет  везде разный, то как БД понять, какой именно title вам нужен для brand1 или article1 если это будет рандомное значение идентификатора записи в итоге?

Comment: Если их там 5 штук то выводить просто первую найденную запись и все

Comment: а в чём смысл этого? В итоге если article1 10 уникальных, то в колонке brand1 уже будут не уникальные значения (нууууу либо NULL).

Comment: DISTINCT в MySQL работает только с полной записью, без вариантов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  `brand1` as `brand`,
  `article1` as `article`,
  ANY_VALUE(`title2`) as `title`
from ...
GROUP BY 1,2
```